# Непонятный результат выполнения

Tags: c++

Исходный код:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(INT_MAX, 1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

> -2147483648

Почему так получилось? искал не нашел ответа.

Comment: А само имя INT_MAX ничего не подсказывает? А по факту - произошло обычное переполнение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас произошло переполнение значения int при добавлении 1 к максимальному значению.

Можете попробовать перевести INT_MAX в двоичное представление руками, получите набор единиц и ноль в начале, который отвечает за знак плюс. Добавляете 1 в двоичном виде, и получаете в знаковом разряде 1 вместо 0 и все остальные нули. Если посмотрите на способ педставления в машине отрицательных чисел, то увидите, что этим представляется INT_MIN - 1 и все осталные нули. Посмотрите, например, в Windows калькуляторе.

Answer (score 4):

Если, к примеру, тип int занимает 4 байта и используется система представления целых чисел дополнением до 2, то `INT_MAX` можно представить в шестнадцатиричном виде следующим образом

```
7FFFFFFF
```

то есть все биты кроме знакового бита установлены в единицу.

Если к этому числу прибавить 1, то получится

```
80000000
```

то есть число с установленным знаковым битом. Это представление наименьшего отрицательного значения для типа `int` которое равно `INT_MIN`.

Это значение и было выведено на консоль в десятичном виде.

В общем случае такое присвоение для знаковых целых чисел, когда имеет место переполнение, является неопределенным поведением.